# I need help with boot-repair

Tags: boot-repair

I cant boot Windows

Here is my 
 boot-repair log file

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11963461

greets

Comment: Boot-Repair only can fix minor Windows issues. And grub only boots a working Windows. You probably need your Windows repair CD or flash drive to make Windows repairs. Did you leave Windows hibernated or needing chkdsk? I might first try using Boot-Repair to temporarily restore a Windows boot loader and see if f8 gets you into Windows repairs. Otherwise your Windows repairCD is required. After you fix Windows use Boot-Repair to restore grub to MBR.

Answer (score 1):

Download the boot-repair iso (613MB download) here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Burn this iso to a usb using a program called Rufus

https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Use these settings:

[image]

Reboot your computer and press an fkey such as f1, f2, f10, f11, f12 (depends on your computer model) in order to boot from your usb.

Boot from your usb.
Click Recommended Repair. This automatically fixes any problems that occurs. After the repair is done, reboot.

Comment: i already did recommended repair
i still cant boot windows thats why i posted the log file

Comment: What does your computer say on the screen when you boot up normally?

Comment: it shows the grub-loader but i can only select ubuntu